# Object is possible undefined? Typescript C#

Tags: typescript

I am trying to get the total of the order but I am getting this undefined error.

```
`<td>{{item.unitPrice * item.quantity}}</td>`
```

Things I tried `item?.unitPrice * item?.quantity`

Comment: if item or either unitPrice or quantity are undefined then you're going to be doing a multiplication between at least one undefined term which is NaN.

Comment: Yeah, both are undefined. How can fix this error if I remove undefined I am getting another error. @apokryfos

Comment: Usually if something is potentially undefined you'd need to have a default e.g. like `((item?.unitPrice)??0)`, though in your case it's probably better to do `item.unitPrice === undefined || item.quantity === undefined ? 'Unknown' : (item.unitPrice*item.quantity)` or something to that effect

Comment: How does this relate to C#?  Please provide a [mre] suitable for demonstrating your issue and only your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE.